# WinUI keeps plating the package logo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winui-3

In multiple cases our WinUI app is using plated versions of the logo. This occurs primarily for the package logo, but occurs on some systems when doing a search for the installed application as well (this last one seems to only occur on Windows 10, which I think implies the App Icon works correctly, but the Tiles don't?).

I've already tried supplying unplated versions, by adding copies of the files package logo and tiles with both the {IconName}.scale-{ScaleFactor}_altform-lightunplated.png scheme, {IconName}.scale-{ScaleFactor}_altform-unplated.png, and {IconName}.scale-{ScaleFactor}_altform-colorful_theme-light.png.

However, none of these seem to work, and Visual Studio also doesn't show them in the appxmanifest Visual Assets tab.

The App Icon does seem to work properly though, and does have the alternate assets listed.

The copied files are found in the project's Assets filter/folder in Visual Studio however, which seems to imply they are being added to the project?

Does anyone know how I can ensure the icons/tiles will be displayed without the background plating? I'm assuming I either have something set incorrectly in visual studio, or using the wrong filename additions, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you set them in *Package.appxmanifest* manually? Do your assets have proper width and height px?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I'm not sure with what you mean setting them manually? Is there an xml bit I should add to the file? The assets are properly sized, from what I can tell. The icons do show up, it's just that windows keeps adding a plated background to them. From what I've read that means you need to add copies of the file with an unplated modifier, but those don't seem to be getting used.

Comment: Is [Tailor your resources for language, scale, high contrast, and other qualifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast) helpful?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I tried using the qualifiers found there, but they don't seem to be doing anything

Answer (score 0):

The App Icon setting works for me. I only concentrate on **targetsize** of [ResourceContext.QualifierValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcecontext.qualifiervalues?view=winrt-22621). Also see [TargetSize and Scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast#scale).

This is the App Icon Setting.

[image]

This is appearance.

[image]

[image: A256P]

[image]

Update:

[image]

Using "Generate" will generate unplated Taskbar picture.

[image]

[image]